# JQueryUI Autocomplete with external text file as a data source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using JQuery Autocomplete in a project.
And i want that the source of this autocomplete is set to be a text file.

Content Of text.txt File
`[{ label:"AAA", url:""},
  { label:"BBB", url:""},
  { label:"CCC", url:""},
]`

How i can implement this data in to a JQuery Autocomplete.
I am trying this but this is not working.

`$( "#textbox" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'text.txt',
   });`

where `textbox` is the id of my textbox and text.txt is the text file.

Glad if somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI autocomplete expects the properties `value` and `label`. So `url` does not work by default. So try to rename those properties and see if it works.

If you want or need to use other properties, you can write a custom autocomplete plugin based on the original, only overriding the essential methods.

For example (using your `label` and `url` above):

```
if (typeof ($.ui.autocomplete) != 'undefined') {
    $.widget('custom.autocompleteCustom', $.ui.autocomplete, {
        _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
            // Customize the <li> below to influence what is actually shown
            return $('<li>')
                   .append($('<a>').html(item.label + '<br>' + item.url))
                   .appendTo(ul);
        }
    });
}
```

You have now registered a plugin called `autocompleteCustom`. You can use it like this:

```
$('#someElement').autocompleteCustom({
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        // You can access ui.item.label, ui.item.url here
    },
    source: '/some/url'
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If i use the above text file as inline data,then it works perfectly.
I dont have any problem with the url p[roperty..but the thing is that i am not able to read it from the external text file

Comment: Do you mean with 'external' txt file that it is on another domain?

Comment: no i mean to read it from a local text file

Comment: I see... Try to validate the JSON using [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com/) (sometimes there are 'invisible' characters in the file, tabs, line breaks, and what have you. 
Also check if the path to the text file is correct (relative to the url of the page with the autocomplete on it.

Comment: thanx for the help..i am able work it out with JSON fle.

Comment: now the problem is that whenever i am typing anything in the textbox,it is showing all the values i.e. all the data of the autocomplete.How to get rid of this??

Comment: Can you recreate your problem on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? That way we can look at your code and help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hsingla/Nmh85/4/
This is the fiddle..in this i am able to read the text file..but now i want that both the splitted parts of text file should be assigned to label and url property of the autocomplete data

Comment: I've updated your Fiddle, check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nmh85/6/. Is this what you were looking for? I've added code to loop through the lines from the txt file, split up each line and add it to the `data` array.